# error 75 path/file access lotus notes while deleting files

Tags: path, lotus-notes

I have a lotus notes agent which takes some files from the server and does some processing and then deletes those files.
For deleting we have used the Kill command. It was working fine, but now we are getting the error "path/file access". Could anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Looks like `sharing access violation`. The file your agent is trying to delete is being held by another process.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are NSF files and your code is opening them as NotesDatabase objects via the server, the files on disk will not be closed even after you are done using them and the objects are gone. That's because the server maintains a cache of open NSF files. You cannot delete the files until they are out of the cache. (This may or may not be true if you specified "" instead of the server name when you opened the NotesDatabase object. I don't recall, but if the workaround had been as easy as just opening locally using "", I think we would have done that.)

To get around this in the past, what I have done is just leave the files on disk and write another agent that runs once per day to clean them up.  It's ugly, but it was the only way to deal with the problem.

Comment: There was a file which did not have enough permissions to delete the file which caused the issue.